# PyCharm не видит модуль ExifRead (ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'exifread')

Tags: python, python-3.x, pycharm

Собственно установил exifread, а PyCharm благополучно его не видит, при этом selenium, установленный таким же путём видит.

```
C:\Users\админ>pip3 install exifread
Requirement already satisfied: exifread in c:\users\админ\appdata\local\packages\pythonsoftwarefoundation.python.3.8_qbz5n2kfra8p0\localcache\local-packages\python38\site-packages (2.3.1)
```

При этом командная строка без проблем:

```
C:\Users\админ>python3
Python 3.8.6 (tags/v3.8.6:db45529, Sep 23 2020, 15:52:53) [MSC v.1927 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import exifread
```

Answer (score 0):

Неправильно искал ответ, пока писал вопрос понял, что не видит именно PyCharm, в общем решение:
В PyCharm File-> Settings -> Project: "Имя проекта" -> Project interpetator -> "Шестерёнка" -> ShowAll -> Show paths of the selected interptetator ("Папка с ветками") -> "+" и добавляем тот самый путь что говорил pip3 при попытке повторной установке, в моём случае
"c:\users\админ\appdata\local\packages\pythonsoftwarefoundation.python.3.8_qbz5n2kfra8p0\localcache\local-packages\python38\site-packages"